# Using random IvParameterSpec, the decryption doesn't work

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, encryption, cryptography

Trying to define UDF functions in Spark to encrypt/decrypt columns in a DataFrame. I am using two encryption functions, one of which uses a random IvParameterSpec (IV). What is not clear to me is how to use the decryption. I know that is the worst thing in the world to use a fixed IV, and to reuse a IV with the same key.

```scala
val encryptUDF = udf((initVecText: String, key : String, text : String) => {
    val Algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
    val Key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(key), "AES")
    val IvSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVecText.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key, IvSpec)
    new String(Base64.getEncoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("utf-8"))), "utf-8")
})

val encryptUDF2 = udf((key : String, text : String) => {
    val Algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
    val Key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(key), "AES")
    val rand = new SecureRandom()
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](16)
    rand.nextBytes(bytes)
    val ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bytes)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Algorithm)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key, ivSpec)
    new String(Base64.getEncoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("utf-8"))), "utf-8")
})

val dencryptUDF = udf((initVector: String, key : String, text : String) => {
    val iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    val skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(key), "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv)
    val original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder.decode(text))
    new String(original)
})

val dencryptUDF2 = udf((key : String, text : String) => {
    val rand = new SecureRandom()
    val bytes = new Array[Byte](16)
    rand.nextBytes(bytes)
    val iv = new IvParameterSpec(bytes)
    val skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder.decode(key), "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv)
    val original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder.decode(text))
    new String(original)
})
```

Examples (not a Scala snippet):

```scala
text="417701467673"
key="YWFhYWJiYmJjY2NjZGRkZGVlZWVmZmZmZ2dnZ2hoaGg="
initVec1="InitVec_FAKEVEC1"
initVec2="InitVec_FAKEVEC2"

// encryption
CASE 1: encryptUDF(initVec1, key, text) => "h0iI8IWv4sCaEhMOdGU6pw==" // does not change if rerun twice
CASE 2: encryptUDF(initVec2, key, text) => "DVs9geuiNB2VPkwG1OSuTA==" // does not change if rerun twice
CASE 3: encryptUDF2(key, text)          => "3XTQwfjBN77GTMd5Xk2o3w==" // always a random output at each run

// decryption

// CASE 1:
dencryptUDF(initVec1, key, "h0iI8IWv4sCaEhMOdGU6pw==") => "417701467673" // OK, using the same IV
dencryptUDF(initVec2, key, "h0iI8IWv4sCaEhMOdGU6pw==") => "417701464673" // WRONG! using another IV (note it is a different number)
dencryptUDF2(key,          "h0iI8IWv4sCaEhMOdGU6pw==") => javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using a random IV

// CASE 2:
dencryptUDF(initVec1, key, "DVs9geuiNB2VPkwG1OSuTA==") => "417701467673" // WRONG! using another IV 
dencryptUDF(initVec2, key, "DVs9geuiNB2VPkwG1OSuTA==") => "417701464673" // OK, using the same IV
dencryptUDF2(key,          "DVs9geuiNB2VPkwG1OSuTA==") => javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using a random IV

// CASE 3:
dencryptUDF(initVec1, key, "3XTQwfjBN77GTMd5Xk2o3w==") => javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using initVec1
dencryptUDF(initVec2, key, "3XTQwfjBN77GTMd5Xk2o3w==") => javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using initVec2
dencryptUDF2(key,          "3XTQwfjBN77GTMd5Xk2o3w==") => javax.crypto.BadPaddingException using a random IV
```

The exception:

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:989)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:76)
  at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:71)
  ... 16 more
```

Comment: Your "encryptUDF2" function generates a random IV (that is good) but you need exact this IV for decryption. Usually the IV is prepended to the ciphertext (sometimes separated by a ':' for easier splitting o decryption). You could prepend the iv directly to the cipher.doFinal-output and build a (Base64) iv|ciphertext. On decryption side you would first decode the copmpete ciphertext, take the first 16 bytes as IV and the rest as ciphertext for decryption. As the ciphertext needs not be secret but unique it is OK to send the IV in public.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Fehr, I think I got your suggestion. Is it a common/good practice to prepend the IV to the final Base64 output? Can you please also explain your last part of your comment "the ciphertext needs to be unique"?

Comment: Simply a typo - I meant the IV (initialization vector) needs to be unique, not the ciphertext of course - sorry for that.

Comment: Roger that. Is there any strong reason for not reusing the same IV with the same key? I'd need to analyse the data even though it's encrypted (because the encrypted result will be the same for the same input, so running some simple query will still be possible).

Comment: Please don't reuse the IV with the same key - it makes your encryption vulnerable. You find a lot of articles here on SO and crypto/security stacks.